# Conflicting lifecycle mapping (plugin execution "org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.0.0:bundle

Tags: java, maven

I've imported xxx maven project, then I got:

> error in pom.xml
>   Conflicting lifecycle mapping (plugin execution "org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.0.0:bundle
>   (execution: default-bundle, phase: package)"). To enable full functionality, remove the conflicting 
>   mapping and run Maven->Update Project Configuration.
>       pom.xml /xxx-core   line 1  Maven Project
>   Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Comment: Have you tried removing the conflicting mapping as it suggests? Pasting the pom file in question will help - it's impossible to offer guidance without that :)

Comment: if the project build in command line, it might be eclipse plugin that create the conflict